# VirtualBox lags on a 4k monitor

Tags: virtualbox

Anyone had a problem with virtual box on a 4k monitor. It works slow with high resolutions, despite memory, core number, and graphic memory settings. Anyone have a solution for that ?

Comment: No, I've not experienced this